# Add background color in webpart titles by custom theme/spcolor

Tags: office-365, theme, spcolor

I am using O365. I created a custom theme and a custom spcolor file. Is it possible to set a background color in the webpart titles? Something like this:

[image]
I try something like this in the developer toolbar and works fine. But the target is now to implement it in my custom theme/spcolor file.

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain .ms-webpart-chrome-title {
    background-color: #008ad9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a `CSS` file and attach it to the master page (if you want this globally all over the site to be the same) or you can create a script editor webpart on a specific page and put the `CSS` code in there. Put the code between `<style></style>` tags.

You can use selectors like these:

```
.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText, 
.ms-webpart-titleText a {
    background-color: #4daea9 !important;
}
.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText, 
.ms-webpart-titleText a:hover {     
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
.s4-wpcell > .ms-webpart-chrome, 
.s4-wpActive > .ms-webpart-chrome {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Notice that in SP, you would sometimes need to write *!important* behind a value in order to make it work.

Comment: So the answer is that it is not possible in a custom theme/spcolor file? A workaround is to implement this in a custom css file or script editor webpart.

Comment: In themes, you can only set the basic font, colors, accents, background picture and choose Oslo/Seattle masterpage. I wouldn't call using CSS a workaround. It is the only and best way if you want to go beyond basic styling and branding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your masterpage and rename, using Sharepoint Design and edit her. Add a new CSS file reference, like this:

```
        <sharepoint:cssregistration name="/sites/dev/siteassets/content/layout_cliente.css" after="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

In your CSS file, you need to add this code: `.ms-webpart-chrome-title {
        background-color: #efefef !important;
        }`

you need to add !important in some properties.